# Scope voltage drop across a 7R5 resistor

Tags: oscilloscope, probe

I am currently measuring the current draw of a PCB and have managed to get down into the uA range. I am able to read 8uA when I use my TENMA 72-7780 as a current sensor.

However when I use a 7R5 current sense resistor and two scope probes either side of the resistor, both referenced to the ground connection of the N93CX power supply I get a ~600uA calculated current draw from V = IR, 0V005 = I 7R5 .

I had a look at the input resistance of my probes ( P6060 ) and they are 10MR, which should only give ~0.3uA draw. The power supply has a ~0.5m cable from it to the 7R5 resistor. The scope probes are ground referenced by their clips to the end of the ground cable.

**Does anyone have any idea where this 600uA calculation error is coming in?**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fouMgv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is your current sense resistor in the high side?  That's the only time it makes sense to do it the way you are.  That's probably the source of the error - the amplifiers and attenuators in the two channels aren't perfect.  Probably easier to measure low side.  That's one probe and a ground connection.

Comment: Try swapping the two scope channels over to see if the readings are the same.

Comment: Yeah, the resistor is on the high side. I measured a voltage drop of 8mV, or 1mA, one way and 6mV, or 800uA, the other way.

Comment: Does 3V751 means 3.751V? And 0V005 means 0.005V or 5mV.

Comment: Yeah, apologies it's a convention I learned.

Comment: Why are you not using your MultiMeter to make this voltage measurement? It has no grounding issues and probably has better precision and accuracy than your oscilloscope.

Comment: Communication is generally easier if it makes sense to all.  Wouldn't 5mV make more sense than a code 0V005?  It even hurts the eyes.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, fair point, i'll use that convention in the future on this forum. Frosty, I wanted to use my scope probes as it allowed me to see the ICs behaviour in a graph, but a multimeter might suffice in some conditions.

Comment: If your oscope is sophisticated enough, it will have a signal-path self-calibration option that should bring all channels into closer agreement. I am often surprised on how infrequently this supposedly monthly procedure is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Calibrating the gain on each channel is critical for differential mode (DM) with this very low DM/CM ratio. 7mV/3.7V * 100%= 0.19%.  You cannot do this by eye on the scope so a DSO calibration is key and may not be easy to adjust.

**For resolution this and power dissipation reasons, a 1% max Vdrop is computed for current sense** R or 75mV is often standard.  This raises your load regulation error by 1% which is tolerable.

Thus I would suggest a 75 Ohm R and expect a 53mV drop with 700uA drain.

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused, there are alot of 75 related numbers about and i'm not sure if there is confusion. You say to use a 1% max Vdrop resistor, which for 3V7 would be 0V37. I then take my max expected current load, say 5mA, and calculate the current sense resistor from that,  i.e. 74R. Which is nearly equal to your 75R quoted resistor?

Comment: Also, most oscilloscopes have 8 or 10 bit ADCs. Using 4 V range and 10 bit resolution, the LSB is 4mV. It is not suitable for this kind of measurement.